# Code review: const char * modification

Tags: c++, g++, constants

I just wrote following code and it's working with `g++`. It shouldn't work. Why is it working?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        //char const *cstr;
        const char *cstr;
        char *cptr;
        std::cin>>cptr;
        cstr = cptr;
        cstr = "CPP";
        cout<<cstr;
        return 0;
}
```

as it is apparent that `cstr` is `const` so it's modification in line `cstr = "CPP";` should not work, but it is working. Why?

Comment: That program is undefined, but not for that reason.

Comment: When you say "it's working with `g++`", do you mean it runs correctly, or just that it compiles.  I would expect to crash with a core dump.

Comment: @MartinBonner It runs correctly.

Comment: So it does!  http://cpp.sh/7jcmn.  I do get a nice warning though.  You need to get rid of that error.

Comment: "Why is it working?" -- that's the wonderful thing about undefined behavior: it may do exactly what you expect it to do, purely by accident. It is **not** working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cstr` is a non-constant pointer to a constant. It can be assigned to and reassigned.

A constant pointer to a constant would be `char const* const cstr`.

Comment: For completeness, a constant pointer to non-const would be `char * const cstr`;

Comment: **I messed up**, I am always messing up definitions when it comes to `const` and `pointers`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Maxim Egorushkin, Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: If you have difficulty with `const` and pointers, remember "`const` goes to the *right* of what it is making constant".  (There is a special hack that allows you to put it to the left if there is nothing to the right.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I blame books that teach people to put `const` on the left. The right place is on the right.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin it is not just books that use const on the left. The c++ standard itself also uses the syntax and it is common in many code bases. The choice is a matter of taste. Significant "blame" is on Dennis Ritchie who chose to not disallow const on left when he designed C.

Answer (score 0):

This code causes undefined behaviour (if there is any input on `cin`):

```
std::cin>>cptr;
```

The meaning of that code is to read characters from `cin` and write them into the space pointed to by `cptr`. But you did not initialize `cptr`.

When a program has [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939), anything can happen, including "working as expected".

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question the OP was asking (which was about a confusion between `char const * p` and `char * const p`).  I agree that the code has UB btw.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const char *cstr;
> ```
>
> as it is apparent that `cstr` is const

No, it isn't.

It is non-`const`, but the thing that it points to is `const`.

Furthermore, you're attempting to read into a `char` buffer that does not exist.

Stop using C-strings, and get yourself some shiny `std::string`s instead.

Comment: I am more comfortable with `std::string` but in interviews I mess up with C-Strings.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who gets confused like I do when it comes to pointers with const declarations, use http://cdecl.org/.